# Is it possible to detect class context in an inherited static method?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

OK, that title is a little unclear, but I can't think of a better way of putting it, other than explaining it...

Say I have a class `Animal`, with a static, generic method:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : Animal {
  // stuff to create, initialize and return an animal of type T
}
```

And I have subclasses `Dog`, `Cat`, `Hamster` etc.  In order to get a `Dog`, I can write:

```
Dog d = Animal.Create<Dog>();
```

or

```
Dog d = Dog.Create<Dog>();
```

which is really the same thing.  But it seems kinda silly to have to write `Dog` so many times, since I'm already invoking the static method through the `Dog` subclass.

Can you think of any clever way of writing a `Create()` method in the base class so that I could invoke

```
Dog d = Dog.Create();
Cat c = Cat.Create();
Hamster h = Hamster.Create();
```

without writing a `Create()` method in each of the subclasses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the Animal class generic.

```
class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        // Don't know what you'll be able to do here
    }
}

class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{

}
```

But how the `Animal` class knows how to create instances of derived types?

Comment: You'll probably want to restrict `T` to Animals: `class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>`

Comment: The code inside Create() will call virtual/abstract methods, that's how it'll create instances of derived types.

Comment: Actually, I have to comment again, because this idea of having Animal<T> forcing T to be of type Animal<T> is just sheer genius.  At first glance it looks like infinite recursion, but it's not; it's a really elegant piece of logic that has just made my life a HECKUVA lot easier.  So thanks again - I wish I could vote you up more!  :)

Comment: I'm using this kind of constraint for my presenters, for exemple:

interface IPresenter<TPresenter, TView> : IPresenter
        where TView : IView<TPresenter>
        where TPresenter : IPresenter<TPresenter, TView>

Answer (score 2):

I would make the Animal class abstract with a static Create method; it's effectively a starting point for a factory. In fact, it looks like you're undoing a factory class.

If you add an abstract *Initialize* method to the Animal class, the Create method becomes:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : Animal {
  T animal = new T();   //may need a "new" in the declaration
  animal.Initialize();  //or Create or whatever or you put this logic
                        //   in the constructor and don't call this at all.
  return animal;
}
```

Comment: Animal can't be a static class. However, if you want to delegate the creation to each derived types, it could be a good idea to make Animal abstract, and the method Initialize abstract instead of virtual.

Comment: Good catch.  That wasn't the intent.

Comment: @Romain -- well put, I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers on ways around it, you can see using reflection that Create will always still be part of Animal, not the derived class.