# How to inherit a generic static method in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1400317/7850) over 10 years ago, about C#, and got a good answer there. Now I'm trying to do the same thing in Java.

Say I have an abstract class `Animal`. I want a static method `create()` in that class, that will return a value of the type of whatever the *subclass* is. I managed this in C# using the following structure:

```
public class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>, new()
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        var t = new T();
        // do generic stuff on the new T instance
        return t;
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{

}

//usage:
var dog = Dog.Create();
```

This worked a charm in C#. But now I'm trying to replicate this structure in Java, and hitting a wall. One big wall is that it seems that [you can't have static generic members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445464/7850). So this would seem to be a bit of a showstopper. But I'm an optimistic kind of guy, and maybe some Java expert out there has come up with a totally out of the box pattern for achieving more or less what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: [Create instance of generic type in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in Java you can't construct an instance off a type variable like that.

As a quick alternative, you can use factories that your code aids with a concrete constructor call

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface AnimalFactory<T extends Animal> {
    T create();

    static <U extends Animal> AnimalFactory<U> ofClass(Class<U> type) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return type.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    static <U extends Animal> AnimalFactory<U> ofSupplier(Supplier<U> creator) {
        return creator::get;
    }
}
```

Then you can call that in your `Animal` static methods (you can indeed reuse it for other types):

```
class Animal {
    static <T extends Animal> T create(Class<T> type) {
        T instance = AnimalFactory.ofClass(type)
                .create();
        // do generic stuff on the new T instance
        return instance;
    }

    static <T extends Animal> T create(Supplier<T> creator) {
        T instance = AnimalFactory.ofSupplier(creator)
                .create();
        // do generic stuff on the new T instance
        return instance;
    }
}
```

In the end, your calling code can look as below. I used a lambda and a reflection-based approaches. You pick.

```
Dog d = Animal.create(Dog.class);
Dog e = Animal.create(Dog::new);
```

Of course, you can skip the static methods in `Animal` altogether and use `AnimalFactory` directly (interfaces can now have static methods that you can use to run the `// do generic stuff on the new T instance` logic)